# WebSocket server refusing all connections in Django Channels

Tags: python, django, reactjs, websocket, django-channels

I was doing a chat with django (backend) and react (frontend). I use Django Channels to create the WebSocket server, but it isn't working : when trying to connect with React, it throws
`Forums.jsx:61 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/forums/divers/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in the navigator console. This morning it was working, but this afternoon, after having closed and reopened the 2 servers, it isn't working. I only started a system to store the messages in the database during this time. The consumer:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json
from .models import Message

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.forum = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["forum"]

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.forum,
            self.channel_name
        )
        print("connect func")
        self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.forum,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        print(message)
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.forum,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        #await sync_to_async(Message.objects.create)(message=message["message"], )
        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

opening of WebSocket client:

```
class Forum extends Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        ...
        this.URL = constants.BACKEND_WS + "/forums/" + this.state.forum + "/";
        this.ws = new WebSocket(this.URL)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("didmount");
        this.ws.onopen = () => {
            console.log('connected')
        };

        this.ws.onmessage = evt => {
            const message = JSON.parse(evt.data);
            console.log(message);
            this.addMessage(message)
        };

        this.ws.onclose = () => {
            console.log('disconnected');
            this.setState({
                ws: new WebSocket(this.URL),
            })
        }
    }
}
```

the logs of the django server:

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /forums/divers/ [127.0.0.1:52726]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /forums/divers/ [127.0.0.1:52726]
```

mysite/routings.py :

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import forums.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            forums.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

forums/routing.py:

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'forums/(?P<forum>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

If someone could explain me how to resolve this problem, he would really help me.

---

**EDIT :** When I remove `async` and replace `await` by `async_to_sync`, it works. Can someone explain me why it's working in synchronous but not in asynchronous ?

Comment: can you add here how you are running your server

Comment: It's the development server of both React and Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by replacing `WebsocketConsumer` by `AsyncWebsocketConsumer`.

Comment: How do you get `AsyncWebsocketConsumer`? I tried `from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer, AsyncWebsocketConsumer`. Still I have same problem, and getting error: **WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed:**